# How to use json output from external Sparql request directly from browser?

Tags: jquery, json, sparql

Lets say I want json file generated from Dbpedia sparql endpoint http://dbpedia.org/sparql

For now I'm just making a request and it automatically downloads json file to my disk, and I use it locally.

How to use json directly from the endpoint? For example, how to input the request by itself in my code instead of inputting locally saved json file?

More concrete, I request for Federer stats:

```
select * where {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Roger_Federer> ?p ?o filter(lang(?o) = 'en')}
```

Saving output as winner.json and fetching it with this:

```
$.getJSON('json/winner.json', function(json) {
  for(var i = 0; i < json["results"]["bindings"].length; i++) {
    $('#winner').append(json["results"]["bindings"][i]["o"].value + '<br /><br />');
  };
});
```

I want to be able to fetch json directly from the server with my script.

Do I need to play with HTML accept headers or something completely else? Thanks on any tip.

Comment: the main issue is ["same origin policy"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). you can't ajax another website.

Comment: I -think- dbpedia allows it, but not sure.

Comment: @roselan If you could ajax it, how would you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just do:

```
 $.getJSON("http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+*+where+%7B%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FRoger_Federer%3E+%3Fp+%3Fo+filter%28lang%28%3Fo%29+%3D+%27en%27%29%7D%0D%0A&debug=on&timeout=&format=application%2Fsparql-results%2Bjson&save=display&fname=",
  {},
  function(data) {
     console.log('data = ', data);
  });
```

Comment: @ip Woa, that was easy :D Do you maybe know how would I do the same thing with Ajax and manipulating with accept headers?

Comment: so the url (decoded) looks like this: [link](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select * where {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Roger_Federer> ?p ?o filter(lang(?o) = 'en')}
&debug=on&timeout=&format=text/html&save=display&fname=). You can change the format parametar e.g if you want JSON you should put "application/sparql-results+json" if html then "text/html".